# How do you change the theme, icon-set and mouse-theme

Tags: 11.10, themes, customization, appearance, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the “Selected Items” color?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63126/how-do-i-change-the-selected-items-color)

I LOVE the idea for Ubuntu 11.10, but I can't customize it the way I want it.

- Also, how do you change the theme, icon-set and mouse-theme on Ubuntu 11.10?

***Note:*** I won't change OSes, install Gnome Shell or go to an older version because I want the most secure updates, and for other various reasons.

Comment: The first part of your question is already been asked, so I've edited your question to just be about the second part, since this system works best when questions are asked separately. If you have any more questions, just ask them individually, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change GTK3 theme, icon-set and mouse-theme by **gnome-tweak-tool** from the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Ok, but I only want to change the color-scheme, I mean, I want the Radiance Theme, but not the "Ubuntu Orange" in every element (selected text, progress bars, buttons...). How can I change the Color-Scheme?

Comment: Sorry if I bumped this, but I rarely use askubuntu.com, if at all any. The thing is, I'm sick of the orange colour used in the latest Ubuntu, and I wanna keep my current theme. And if this question was already asked, then can someone be a nice lad and give me a point? Oh well, I guess I'll just modify Ubuntu 11.04 (as much as I'd hate to...) Again, apologies...