# How to change the color tone of the Ambiance theme?

Tags: unity, themes, configuration, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the “Selected Items” color?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63126/how-do-i-change-the-selected-items-color)

I am using 12.04. I found a video where [the primary colour of the Unity interface is light blue rather than orange](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2rj18H0M38) (the buttons, the icons, and the Dash icon).  How can you change all orange colours?

[image: Picture of the effect]

Comment: This is a screenshot from my PC. I want to my desktop interface being like on the video. He is using ccsm, too. http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/2213/screenshotfrom201205101.png

Comment: **The colors shown in the screenshot are result of a bug, making it seem like the result of color theme change (which never happened)**

Answer (score 5):

What you're experiencing is a known bug ([Lauchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/968489), [Adobe](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3136745)). Because of it you're seeing some Youtube videos with [blue tint](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/98933845/flash_error_screenshot.jpg).

For more information and a fix see this question: [Flash video appears blue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue)

Comment: I had get inverted colors due to flash player bug.
Thanks for your interest.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question, given the screenshot which was a direct of the bug

Answer (score 5):

This is easily achieved using the themes in ambiance-colors.  (There is also a radiance-colors theme if you prefer the radiance theme.)  To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ravefinity-project/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ambiance-colors
```

After this, use either Ubuntu Tweak or MyUnity or Gnome Tweak to change themes.  You'll find in the list of themes - in all of those tools - a number of new ambiance themes, such as ambiance-blue, ambiance-red, etc.  Make sure to change the theme both under "Window Theme" and under "GTK Theme."

The user in the picture has also installed an icon theme that uses blue folder icons, but I don't know which icon theme it is (although it might be HumanityBlue).  There are a number of them, though. (If you search Google under "Ubuntu icon theme" you'll find quite a few.  I use Faenza, but there are many others available.)

Comment: Note the theme can be download for other distros from here: http://www.ravefinity.com/p/download-ambiance-radiance-colors.html , and that there is a version for radiance can be installed (`radiance-colors`), and a [matching icon theme](http://www.ravefinity.com/p/humanity-colors-icon-theme.html) (`humanity-colors` package) is also available.

Answer (score 4):

The colors used by the DASH, panel and launcher background are generated from the wallpaper they cover. To change theme colors there are three files you need to edit.

```
/usr/share/themes/{theme name}/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
/usr/share/themes/{theme name}/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
/usr/share/themes/{theme name}/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

In the beginning of these files you'll find 4 pairs of core foreground and background colors used in applications based on the gtk 2 and gtk 3 libraries. Pair base_color and text_color are used for the document or text entry portions of windows where bg_color and fg_color are are used for the windows area where icons and labels are displayed. Selected pair is for selected text and the tooltip pair is used for the tips that pop up when you hover over a button or link. These colors may be applied by applications with varying opacity or shadings. The color of text in buttons comes from the fg_color. These sets of labels appear in all three files so I've been changing all three to be the same for any label I change. Here's an example of what I changed in the gtk.css file in the Ambiance theme.

```
/* default color scheme */
@define-color bg_color #cdc3b8;
@define-color fg_color #262626;
@define-color base_color #accdff;
@define-color text_color #262626;
@define-color selected_bg_color #01b9fc;
@define-color selected_fg_color #ffffff;
@define-color tooltip_bg_color #A3D0FF;
@define-color tooltip_fg_color #023C79;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the ubuntu Tweak tool can help you with that.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/

under optimisations/-themes

Comment: I have ubuntu-tweak 0.7.1. But it does not involve optimisation section. There is only themes section but in there I can just change themes. I have installed the ambiance blue theme but it is not like on the image. If you look on the image in the my first thread, the icons haven't been changed. Only, their colours have been changed. So, when I changed the icon theme to the gnome-brave or another one, the applets on the panel are also changing (such as network applet, etc.) On the interface which is shown on my first image, the applets are same like being Ubuntu default.

Comment: He wanted his interface to change from the blue theme to the orange one (like on the video).  To achieve this the video showed using CCSM as the means to achieve this.  I dont think his question is very well written and thought he should have been probed more before answering