# Is there any alternative for gnome-appearance-properties?

Tags: 12.04, themes, gnome, customization

`gnome-appearance-properties` is no more available in `Gnome3` and newer.

I want to change Background and Text colors of Windows, Input Boxes, Selected Items, etc. and customize Theme.

Is there any application available to do that?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/63126/61218). If you think, that question is sufficient you can flag it to close or delete the question (on certain situation). If you wanted something other than that question, please be specific about your question i.e What part of the themes you want to customize. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try `gtk-chtheme` for basic selection of themes. I've also installed `metacity-themes`, `shiki-colors` and customised window buttons through `gconf-editor` under `.../apps/metacity/`.