# Customize color of selection rectangle when clicking-and-dragging on desktop

Tags: themes, customization, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the “Selected Items” color?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63126/how-do-i-change-the-selected-items-color)

When I click and drag on my desktop it shows an orange box, however my My color scheme is blue, so how can I change the rectangle's color to blue to match? please.

I'm using 12.04.
I would like too see customization made easier in future releases please.

Comment: its not a duplicate of that post , as it this is how do I change the click and drag boarder colors not the file selected, also this is 12.04 not version 10. The post you show is th file selected not the same thing.

Comment: It does the same thing - I've done it on my installation of 12.04 to make it silver. The commands are all the same. It's no different.

Comment: See the advice given in [this post.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63126/how-do-i-change-the-selected-items-color) The top answer has worked for me in ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Yep your right thank you , sorry my bad but still you could just have posted the what to do here instead of forcing me to read everything on that page trying to find which post is what I'm looking for. Its like a rat in a maze lol. Any how thank you very much ;)

Comment: Just make sure you try to search for stuff before asking, and have a good read of everything that might be related before you go about asking a question: you never know what might be useful or interesting :) Welcome to the site!