# White text on white background in selections after fresh install in vm

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, text-editor, color-management

I freshly installed Kubuntu 12.04 in my Oracle VM VirtualBox on Windows 7.

Everything works fine except, that if I select any text in many applications (for example Bluefish-Editor) the background is not the standard color, but instead it is white. So I cannot read the text that I selected.

How could this happen?

---

A workaround would be to change the color globally somehow like this:
[How do I change the "Selected Items" color?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63126/how-do-i-change-the-selected-items-color)

Comment: Please add version of Virtual Box, and graphics card of host. Did you succeed in [installing the guest additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox/22745#22745)?

Comment: yes, guest additions are running fine. I will look to the version later, at work

Comment: version of virtualBox is 4.2.8 r83876

Comment: The workaround has no effect, maybe, because it is only for gnome? I use KDE