# how to change selection color in Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: themes, kde

Before posting a question here i have gone through search in askubutu and got this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63126/how-do-i-change-the-selected-items-color) but that didn't help me . may be that suitable for Ubuntu with gnome etc . but not good for Kubuntu .

some can give me a way to change icon selection color in Kubuntu 12.04 . Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KDE has a vast set of configuration options - I'm not at all surprised you can't find this!

Fire up System Settings, and click on Application Appearance.
[image]

Now click on Icons:
[image]

And choose All Icons:
[image]

Now click Set Effect for the "Active" icons at the bottom.
You should see:
[image]

It sounds like you want the icons to change color when they're highlighted, so try playing with the settings for Colorize.

Comment: my issue different , but i got it solved by changing all to defaults . you gave me a new tip . +1 . Thank you.