# Change the "Selected Items" colour for non-focus fields

Tags: unity, 15.10, themes

In Ubuntu 15.10, how does one change the "Selected Items" color for non-focus fields. Here is an example selected line that is coloured brightly when the field has focus:

[image]

However, the selected line is **almost imperceptible** when the field loses focus:

[image]

This question is not a dupe of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63126/how-do-i-change-the-selected-items-color) which asks about changing the "Selected Items" color for focused fields.

Comment: Have you tried another gtk theme? I'm not seeing this issue with Firefox 44.0.2 and Lubuntu 14.04 with a modified Greybird theme (from the shimmer-themes package).

Comment: @DKBose: Thanks. Even after installing that theme it does not appear in my System Settings theme selection. I'll resolve that issue first, then get back to this.

Comment: As I understand it, if you're using Unity, you need to have some tweak tool to change themes.

Comment: @DKBose: You are right, I installed the Numix theme with unity-tweak-tool and the issue is resolved. If you post that as an answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: I don't mind if you post your own answer detailing exactly what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the Ubuntu theme, both the theme and the [Unity Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/) must be installed:

```
$ sudo aptitude install shimmer-themes unity-tweak-tool
```

In the Unity Tweak Tool go to `Appearance -> Theme` and select the new theme. For me, the theme **Numix** resolved the non-focused Selected Items issue.

**This answer is based upon [DK Bose's](https://askubuntu.com/users/248158/dk-bose) very helpful comments.**